# Pass service function reference to child component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have two methods in a service that both hit different controllers for searching my database.  I'd like to make a shared child component which will be used in two different places, however I need each instance to be able to specifically call one of the service methods. For example, these are my methods:

```
// SERVICE
searchOne(search: string){
// do some searching in Controller 1
}

searchTwo(search: string){
// do some searching in Controller 2
}
```

With my shared child component having a similar method to hit the service:

```
// CHILD COMPONENT
@Input(Function) func: Function;

componentSearch(search: string){
    this.func(search);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when trying to pass a function from a parent like so:

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
func = this.service.searchOne;
constructor(private service: Service){}

// PARENT COMPONENT.HTML
<app-child-component [func]="func"></app-child-component>
```

How do I pass access or reference of the service functions into my child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a working Stackblitz for your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raxtho)

Few corrections in your code:

Parent component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  func;

  constructor(private service: AppService){
    this.func = this.service.searchOne;
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
  @Input() func: Function;
  componentSearch(search: string){
    this.func(search);
  }
```